# Label groups from Tukey's test results according to significant

Tags: python, classification, posthoc, tukey

I have a Tukey's test table resulted from `pairwise_tukeyhsd` from the python `statsmodels.stats.multicomp`.

```
    group1  group2  meandiff    lower   upper   reject
0   101     102     0.2917    -0.0425   0.6259  False
1   101     103     0.1571    -0.1649   0.4792  False
2   101     104     -0.1333   -0.4675   0.2009  False
3   101     105     0.0833    -0.2509   0.4175  False
4   101     106     -0.0500   -0.3626   0.2626  False
5   102     103     -0.1345   -0.4566   0.1875  False
6   102     104     -0.4250   -0.7592  -0.0908  True
7   102     105     -0.2083   -0.5425   0.1259  False
8   102     106     -0.3417   -0.6543  -0.0290  True
9   103     104     -0.2905   -0.6125   0.0316  False
10  103     105     -0.0738   -0.3959   0.2482  False
11  103     106     -0.2071   -0.5067   0.0924  False
12  104     105     0.2167    -0.1175   0.5509  False
13  104     106     0.0833    -0.2293   0.3960  False
14  105     106     -0.1333   -0.4460   0.1793  False
```

I have this table as `pandas` `df`. I would like to label (by letters) the groups (101-106) denoting statistical relationships. For this specific example the desired result would be: (I don't mind if the results will be df, a list, a dictionary)

```
group   label
101      ab
102      a
103      ab
104      b
105      ab
106      b
```

As you can see, all groups that share similar letter have an equal mean (reject column = False), and groups that have different letters (reject column = True) have different mean. For example, the mean of group 101 is equal to all of the other groups' means because group 101 has the letter ab, and all of the other groups have either *a* or *b* or *ab*. On the other hand, group 106 only has the letter *b* which indicates that it is similar to all the groups **except** for group 102 that has only the letter *a*.

I could not find an automatic python solution for that. I [saw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982513/how-can-i-classify-post-hoc-test-results-in-r) that R has a package for that called `multcompLetters`, is there something similar in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a couple of days sitting on it, and with no suggested answers/comments from other users, I think I figured it out. Let's say the table from my question is named `df`. The following script is specific for my needs but I hope it can help others. I added comments to facilitate the understanding.

```
    df_True = df.loc[df.reject==True,:]

    letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
    n = 0

    group1_list = df_True.group1.tolist() #get the groups from the df with only True (True df) to a list
    group2_list = df_True.group2.tolist()
    group3 = group1_list+group2_list #concat both lists
    group4 = list(set(group3)) #get unique items from the list
    group5 = [str(i) for i in group4 ] #convert unicode to a str
    group5.sort() #sort the list

    gen = ((i, 0) for i in group5) #create dict with 0 so the dict won't be empty when starts
    dictionary = dict(gen)

    group6 = [(group5[i],group5[j]) for i in range(len(group5)) for j in range(i+1, len(group5))] #get all combination pairs
    for pairs in group6: #check for each combination if it is present in df_True

        print n
        print dictionary

        try:        
            a = df_True.loc[(df_True.group1==pairs[0])&(df_True.group2==pairs[1]),:] #check if the pair exists in the df

        except:
            a.shape[0] == 0 

        if a.shape[0] == 0: #it mean that the df is empty as it does not appear in df_True so this pair is equal

            print 'equal'

            if dictionary[pairs[0]] != 0 and dictionary[pairs[1]] == 0: #if the 1st is populated but the 2nd in not populated
                print "1st is populated and 2nd is empty"      
                dictionary[pairs[1]] = dictionary[pairs[0]]

            elif dictionary[pairs[0]] != 0 and dictionary[pairs[1]] != 0: #if both are populated, check matching labeles
                print "both are populated"
                if len(list(set([c for c in dictionary[pairs[0]] if c in dictionary[pairs[1]]]))) >0: #check if they have a common label
                        print "they have a shared character"
                else:
                    print "equal but have different labels"
                 #check if the 1st group label doesn't appear in anyother labels, if it is unique then the 2nd group can have the first group label
                    m = 0 #count the number of groups that have a shared char with 1st group
                    j = 0 #count the number of groups that have a shared char with 2nd group
                    for key, value in dictionary.iteritems():
                        if key != pairs[0] and len(list(set([c for c in dictionary[pairs[0]] if c in value])))==0:
                            m+=1
                    for key, value in dictionary.iteritems():
                        if key != pairs[1] and len(list(set([c for c in dictionary[pairs[1]] if c in value])))==0:
                            j+=1
                    if m == len(dictionary)-1 and j == len(dictionary)-1: #it means that this value is unique because it has no shared char with another group
                        print "unique"
                        dictionary[pairs[1]] = dictionary[pairs[0]][0]

                    else:
                        print "there is at least one group in the dict that shares a char with the 1st group"                                 
                        dictionary[pairs[1]] = dictionary[pairs[1]] + dictionary[pairs[0]][0]


            else:  # if it equals 0, meaning if the 1st is empty (which means that the 2nd must be also empty)
                print "both are empty"
                dictionary[pairs[0]] = letters[n]
                dictionary[pairs[1]] = letters[n]

        else:

            print "not equal"

            if dictionary[pairs[0]] != 0: # if the first one is populated (has a value) then give a value only to the second 

                print '1st is populated'            
                # if the 2nd is not empty and they don't share a charcter then no change is needed as they already have different labels
                if dictionary[pairs[1]] != 0 and len(list(set([c for c in dictionary[pairs[0]] if c in dictionary[pairs[1]]]))) == 0: 
                    print "no change"

                elif dictionary[pairs[1]] == 0: #if the 2nd is not populated give it a new letter
                    dictionary[pairs[1]] = letters[n+1]

                #if the 2nd is populated and equal to the 1st, then change the letter of the 2nd to a new one and assign its original letter to all the others that had the same original letter       
                elif  dictionary[pairs[1]] != 0 and len(list(set([c for c in dictionary[pairs[0]] if c in dictionary[pairs[1]]]))) > 0:
                    #need to check that they don't share a charcter
                    print "need to add a letter"
                    original_value = dictionary[pairs[1]]
                    dictionary[pairs[1]] = letters[n]
                    for key, value in dictionary.iteritems():
                        if key != pairs[0] and len(list(set([c for c in original_value if c in value])))>0: #for any given value, check if it had a character from the group that will get a new letter, if so, it means  that they are equal and thus the new letter should also appear in the value of the "old" group 
                            dictionary[key] = original_value + letters[n]  #add the original letter of the group to all the other groups it was similar to               

            else:

                print '1st is empty'
                dictionary[pairs[0]] = letters[n]
                dictionary[pairs[1]] = letters[n+1]
                print dictionary
            n+=1

    # get the letter out the dictionary

    labels = list(dictionary.values())
    labels1 = list(set(labels))
    labels1.sort()
    final_label = ''.join(labels1)

    for GroupName in group_names:
        if GroupName in dictionary:
            print "already exists"
        else:
            dictionary[GroupName] = final_label

    for key, value in dictionary.iteritems(): #this keeps only the unique char per group and sort it by group
        dictionary[key] =  ''.join(set(value))
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for you contribution. I had to modify your code a little just to correct some missing stuff and to adapt to python3. Main changes were

- import string (it was missing)
- change dictionary.iteritems to dictionary.items (python3)
- convert all print "..." to print("...") (python3)
- the variable group_names was missing
- force the GroupName to be a str in the group_name loop
- sort the final dictionary into dict2

Your original data is in a csv file now named input2.csv

```
,group1,group2,meandiff,lower,upper,reject
0,101,102,0.2917,-0.0425,0.6259,False
1,101,103,0.1571,-0.1649,0.4792,False
2,101,104,-0.1333,-0.4675,0.2009,False
3,101,105,0.0833,-0.2509,0.4175,False
4,101,106,-0.0500,-0.3626,0.2626,False
5,102,103,-0.1345,-0.4566,0.1875,False
6,102,104,-0.4250,-0.7592,-0.0908,True
7,102,105,-0.2083,-0.5425,0.1259,False
8,102,106,-0.3417,-0.6543,-0.0290,True
9,103,104,-0.2905,-0.6125,0.0316,False
10,103,105,-0.0738,-0.3959,0.2482,False
11,103,106,-0.2071,-0.5067,0.0924,False
12,104,105,0.2167,-0.1175,0.5509,False
13,104,106,0.0833,-0.2293,0.3960,False
14,105,106,-0.1333,-0.4460,0.1793,False
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
import itertools
import string

df = pd.read_csv('input2.csv', index_col=0)

df_True = df.loc[df.reject==True,:]
letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
n = 0

group1_list = df_True.group1.tolist() #get the groups from the df with only True (True df) to a list
group2_list = df_True.group2.tolist()
group3 = group1_list+group2_list #concat both lists
group4 = list(set(group3)) #get unique items from the list
group5 = [str(i) for i in group4 ] #convert unicode to a str
group5.sort() #sort the list

gen = ((i, 0) for i in group5) #create dict with 0 so the dict won't be empty when starts
dictionary = dict(gen)

group6 = [(group5[i],group5[j]) for i in range(len(group5)) for j in range(i+1, len(group5))] #get all combination pairs
for pairs in group6: #check for each combination if it is present in df_True

    print(n)
    print(dictionary)

    try:
        a = df_True.loc[(df_True.group1==pairs[0])&(df_True.group2==pairs[1]),:] #check if the pair exists in the df

    except:
        a.shape[0] == 0

    if a.shape[0] == 0: #it mean that the df is empty as it does not appear in df_True so this pair is equal

        print ('equal')

        if dictionary[pairs[0]] != 0 and dictionary[pairs[1]] == 0: #if the 1st is populated but the 2nd in not populated
            print ("1st is populated and 2nd is empty")
            dictionary[pairs[1]] = dictionary[pairs[0]]

        elif dictionary[pairs[0]] != 0 and dictionary[pairs[1]] != 0: #if both are populated, check matching labeles
            print ("both are populated")
            if len(list(set([c for c in dictionary[pairs[0]] if c in dictionary[pairs[1]]]))) >0: #check if they have a common label
                    print ("they have a shared character")
            else:
                print ("equal but have different labels")
             #check if the 1st group label doesn't appear in anyother labels, if it is unique then the 2nd group can have the first group label
                m = 0 #count the number of groups that have a shared char with 1st group
                j = 0 #count the number of groups that have a shared char with 2nd group
                for key, value in dictionary.items():
                    if key != pairs[0] and len(list(set([c for c in dictionary[pairs[0]] if c in value])))==0:
                        m+=1
                for key, value in dictionary.items():
                    if key != pairs[1] and len(list(set([c for c in dictionary[pairs[1]] if c in value])))==0:
                        j+=1
                if m == len(dictionary)-1 and j == len(dictionary)-1: #it means that this value is unique because it has no shared char with another group
                    print ("unique")
                    dictionary[pairs[1]] = dictionary[pairs[0]][0]

                else:
                    print ("there is at least one group in the dict that shares a char with the 1st group")
                    dictionary[pairs[1]] = dictionary[pairs[1]] + dictionary[pairs[0]][0]


        else:  # if it equals 0, meaning if the 1st is empty (which means that the 2nd must be also empty)
            print ("both are empty")
            dictionary[pairs[0]] = letters[n]
            dictionary[pairs[1]] = letters[n]

    else:

        print ("not equal")

        if dictionary[pairs[0]] != 0: # if the first one is populated (has a value) then give a value only to the second 

            print ('1st is populated')
            # if the 2nd is not empty and they don't share a charcter then no change is needed as they already have different labels
            if dictionary[pairs[1]] != 0 and len(list(set([c for c in dictionary[pairs[0]] if c in dictionary[pairs[1]]]))) == 0:
                print ("no change")

            elif dictionary[pairs[1]] == 0: #if the 2nd is not populated give it a new letter
                dictionary[pairs[1]] = letters[n+1]

            #if the 2nd is populated and equal to the 1st, then change the letter of the 2nd to a new one and assign its original letter to all the others that had the same original letter       
            elif  dictionary[pairs[1]] != 0 and len(list(set([c for c in dictionary[pairs[0]] if c in dictionary[pairs[1]]]))) > 0:
                #need to check that they don't share a charcter
                print ("need to add a letter")
                original_value = dictionary[pairs[1]]
                dictionary[pairs[1]] = letters[n]
                for key, value in dictionary.items():
                    if key != pairs[0] and len(list(set([c for c in original_value if c in value])))>0: #for any given value, check if it had a character from the group that will get a new letter, if so, it means  that they are equal and thus the new letter should also appear in the value of the "old" group 
                        dictionary[key] = original_value + letters[n]  #add the original letter of the group to all the other groups it was similar to               

        else:

            print ('1st is empty')
            dictionary[pairs[0]] = letters[n]
            dictionary[pairs[1]] = letters[n+1]
            print (dictionary)
        n+=1

# get the letter out the dictionary

labels = list(dictionary.values())
labels1 = list(set(labels))
labels1.sort()
final_label = ''.join(labels1)

df2=pd.concat([df.group1,df.group2])
group_names=df2.unique()
for GroupName in group_names:
    if GroupName in dictionary:
        print ("already exists")
    else:
        dictionary[str(GroupName)] = final_label

for key, value in dictionary.items(): #this keeps only the unique char per group and sort it by group
    dictionary[key] =  ''.join(set(value))

dict2 = dict(sorted(dictionary.items())) # the final output
```